# symfony- show a form after submission

Tags: php, symfony

i have a simple form  and i want display another form after submitting in the same template twig
mycontroller:

```
  /**
 * @Route("/admin/client/modifier", name="modifier")
 * @Method({"GET","POST"})
 */
public function modifierAction(Request $request)
{
        $form=$this->createFormBuilder()
                   ->add('raisonSocial', TextType::class)
                   ->add('Rechrecher', SubmitType::class)
                   ->getForm();

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

        } ;
    return $this->render('myTemplate/Clients/modifierClient.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve? Be more precise

Comment: i have a simple form in my template : [link](http://www2.0zz0.com/2017/07/22/11/754431273.png)  the form that i want display : [link](https://pastebin.com/tKuWkEmV) my template [link](https://pastebin.com/9dwM3Txt)

Comment: up up up up up up

Answer (score 0):

You have to adapt your answer to the correct way. I do not remember exactly the correct `$request->request->get` syntax so check the documentation.

Anyway... I guess you can achieve this by using a render controller inside your twig based on some parameters that come from the post/get of your form submission or via ajax (but you already said you don't know how to do this via ajax).

So let's say you search "test" you should have inside your `$request->request->get` your parameter `test`.

you should to something like this in your twig file:

> your div where you want to have the form displayed

```
<div>
{% if app.request.get('your_key') == 'test' %}
    {{ render(controller(''AppBundle:Article:recentArticles'')) }}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

This means that you will need to create yourself a new action in `ArticleController` called `recentArticles` where you will have your new form.

You can find more details about this on the symfony documentation here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Comment: thanks for answering , i'dont know how use ajax in this situation ! i need a tuto

Comment: Then use the first part of the answer where you do not need ajax.